# Import Esri/ArcGIS .e00 files to QGIS on Linux (getting error message)?

Tags: qgis, import, e00

I can't seem to import Esri .e00 files into QGIS, and I can't figure out why.  I'm trying to import files I've downloaded from ftp://ftp.granit.sr.unh.edu/pub/GRANIT_Data/Vector_Data/Environment_and_Conservation/d-landcover/d-1995/.  Based on the answer to this question: [Adding .e00 data into QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/50121/adding-e00-data-into-qgis), I tried importing lan23205.e00 as a vector file, and get an error message stating that it is "not a valid or recognized data source"

What is going on here?

Note: I'm running Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: Took the answer too literally. The data import fine as raster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are raster coverages, not vector.  I was able to open one of them using the Add Raster Layer button in QGIS.  Here's what gdalinfo says about the file:

```
Driver: E00GRID/Arc/Info Export E00 GRID
Files: lan231.e00
Size is 345, 223
Coordinate System is `'
Origin = (1059406.313363000100000,1023401.084660700100000)
Pixel Size = (93.493327489275273,-93.493327489238126)
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( 1059406.313, 1023401.085)
Lower Left  ( 1059406.313, 1002552.073)
Upper Right ( 1091661.511, 1023401.085)
Lower Right ( 1091661.511, 1002552.073)
Center      ( 1075533.912, 1012976.579)
Band 1 Block=345x1 Type=Int32, ColorInterp=Undefined
Min=200.000 Max=791.000
Minimum=200.000, Maximum=791.000, Mean=448.930, StdDev=75.639
NoData Value=-2147483647
```

Comment: e00 files are not necessarily raster.  http://www.digitalpreservation.gov/formats/fdd/fdd000291.shtml.  There is still for windows available a standalone converter to convert e00 to coverage.  http://www.esri.com/apps/products/download/index.cfm?fuseaction=download.main&downloadid=175

Comment: I should have been more clear, I meant that in this case the e00 were raster, not vector.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to convert it to another format using ogr2ogr:

http://geospatialdesktop.com/2011/11/converting-e00-files/