# Adding .e00 file into QGIS

Tags: qgis, import, e00

I am trying to read .e00 file in qgis but it says "Invalid Data Source". I don't know whether it is a vector or raster data. So, I tried importing it as both vector and raster but am getting same message. The file in mention is soil texure data found [here](ftp://dbftp.essc.psu.edu/pub/data/1997-0009/mu_poly.e00.gz).

I am wondering if there is a way to change the file format or to open it as such in QGIS.

**EDIT**:I did go through the answer of the question [Adding .e00 data into QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/50121/adding-e00-data-into-qgis)

which suggests that I can import it as such as a vector but I am getting the error as above.

Comment: check this answer out https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/50121/adding-e00-data-into-qgis

Comment: @mr.adam "Invalid Data Source: C:\Users\Kuljeet\Downloads\Compressed\mu_poly.e00\us48_mu_geo.e00 is not a valid or recognized data source" is the error I receive if I try importing it as a vector or a raster as answer of the question suggests.

Comment: @KuljeetKeshav you have two dots here 'mu_poly.e00\us48_mu_ge‌​o.e00' you can only have one. try 'mu_poly_e00\us48_mu_ge‌​o.e00' instead

Comment: @Mapperz Tried doing it. Still same problem
When opened as Raster :"Unsupported Data Source:C:\Users\Kuljeet\Downloads\Compressed\mu_polye00\us48_mu_geo.e00 is not a supported raster data source"
When opened as Vector :
"Invalid Data Source: C:\Users\Kuljeet\Downloads\Compressed\mu_polye00\us48_mu_geo.e00 is not a valid or recognized data source"

Comment: but your data is vector - I converted it too see

Comment: @Mappers it is not opening even as a vector

Comment: @KuljeetKeshav download the zip and add in the two mapinfo files in the >comment to answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is comment rather than an answer but the conversion to mapinfo tab created point files and polygons to create this.

[image]

The file is available here for 30 days
https://ufile.io/jwgnj